# INNER JOIN WITH LIKE AND PREFIX

Tags: sql, sql-server

ITEM1 in table A and B-ITEM1 in Table B, I want to join them so A-ITEM1 = B-ITEM with an inner join since they are the same thing only with different prefix. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/*My scripts*/
SELECT TOP 50
    A.ITEMNMBR AS 'Item Number',                    
    A.QTYONHND AS 'Quantity On Hand'    

    FROM [NSR].dbo.[IV00102] A
    INNER JOIN [ART].dbo.[IV00101] B
    ON A.ITEMNMBR = B.ITEMNMBR

ORDER BY A.ITEMNMBR
```

/*The problem with that part is in NSR database the itemnumber is NSR-ITEM1 and for the ART database the item number = ART-ITEM1*/

/*I want the result to show... because is the same item*/
    ITEMNMBR   QTYONHND
    NSR-ITEM1  12
    ART-ITEM1  12

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: If you got any chance, fix your data model. Otherwise you can join on concatenated columns: `ON 'A-' || a.col = b.col`

Comment: I just did Gordon.

Comment: The `dbo` stuff gives this away as SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string functions in `ON` clauses.

Perhaps this one will help.

```
 ON REPLACE(A.ITEMNBR, 'NSR-', 'ART-') = B.ITEMNBR
```

This will "repair" values like `NSR-ITEM1` by turning them into `ART-ITEM1`. Then they can be tested for equality.

But, to be clear, this is not a great solution to your problem. It's brittle because you may have `ITEMNBR` values that don't follow the `NSR-whatever` pattern. Those will not match.

Comment: It's not a question of luck. What do you get from `SELECT ITEMNBR,  REPLACE(ITEMNBR, 'NSR-', 'ART-') FROM  [NSR].dbo.[IV00102]` ? Are you getting the unedited and edited item numbers you expect?

Comment: Hi Jones, After looking I found something that can do what I'm looking for I did this by looking for a specific item and ON SUBSTRING (A.ITEMNMBR , 4 , 200) = SUBSTRING (C.ITEMNMBR, 4, 200) and when I look let's say I do a where to look for item1 it would give me item = NSR-ITEM1 his quantity then next row ART-ITEM1 His quantity on the other database.